# if-else in Solidity Doesn't Work

Tags: solidity, blockchain, function

Im creating a web based medicine anticounterfeit using blockchain and this is my smart contact program:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SupplyChain {
    
    event Added(uint256 index);
    
    struct State{
        string description;
        address person;
    }
    
    struct Product{
        string registrationNumber;
        address creator;
        string productName;
        uint256 productId;
        string genericName;
        string countryOrigin;
        string distributor;
        string importer;
        string manufactureDate;
        string expiryDate;
        uint256 totalStates;
        mapping (uint256 => State) positions;
        uint256 viewCount;
    }
    

    mapping(uint => Product) allProducts;
    uint256 items=0;
    
    function concat(string memory _a, string memory _b) public returns (string memory){
        bytes memory bytes_a = bytes(_a);
        bytes memory bytes_b = bytes(_b);
        string memory length_ab = new string(bytes_a.length + bytes_b.length);
        bytes memory bytes_c = bytes(length_ab);
        uint k = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < bytes_a.length; i++) bytes_c[k++] = bytes_a[i];
        for (uint i = 0; i < bytes_b.length; i++) bytes_c[k++] = bytes_b[i];
        return string(bytes_c);
    }
    
    function newItem(string memory _RGNum ,string memory _PNtext, string memory _GNtext, string memory _COtext, string memory _IM,string memory _DI,  string memory _MDdate, string memory _EDtext) public returns (bool) {
        Product memory added = Product({registrationNumber: _RGNum,creator: msg.sender, totalStates: 0, productName: _PNtext, productId: items, genericName: _GNtext, countryOrigin: _COtext, distributor: _DI,importer:_IM, manufactureDate: _MDdate, expiryDate: _EDtext, viewCount: 0});
        allProducts[items]=added;
        items = items+1;
        emit Added(items);
        return true;
    }


    
    function addState(uint _productId, string memory info) public returns (string memory) {
        require(_productId<=items);
        
        State memory newState = State({person: msg.sender, description: info});
        
        allProducts[_productId].positions[ allProducts[_productId].totalStates ]=newState;
        
        allProducts[_productId].totalStates = allProducts[_productId].totalStates +1;
        return info;
    }
    
    function searchProduct(uint _productId) public returns (string memory) {
        require(_productId<=items);

        if(allProducts[_productId].viewCount > 1){
            string memory output="QR Code already used!";
            return output;
        }else{
            string memory output="Item Status: Verified";
            output=concat(output, "<br>Registration Number: ");
            output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].registrationNumber);
            output=concat(output, "<br>Product Name: ");
            output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].productName);
            output=concat(output, "<br>Generic Name: ");
            output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].genericName);
            output=concat(output, "<br>Dosage Strength: ");
            output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].countryOrigin);
            output=concat(output, "<br>Trader: ");
            output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].distributor);
            output=concat(output, "<br>Importer: ");
            output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].importer);
            output=concat(output, "<br>Manufacture Date: ");
            output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].manufactureDate);
            output=concat(output, "<br>Expiry Date: ");
            output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].expiryDate);
            
            allProducts[_productId].viewCount += 1;
            
            for (uint256 j=0; j<allProducts[_productId].totalStates; j++){
                output=concat(output, allProducts[_productId].positions[j].description);
            }
            return output;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

and the problem is in the function searchProduct();

supposed to be if the viewCount is zero it will display the information about the item while if it was viewed once it will display the "QR already used"

but the output is always the information about the item

Answer (score 0):

Change `>1` into `>0` and it will work.

Initially, `viewCount` is zero. On first `searchProduct` it becomes 1, the second time `searchProduct` is called, `allProducts[_productId].viewCount > 1` is false, hence it returns product details again.

On the third time you should see "QR Code already used!" returned.